# Using ajax to display new database inputs without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using ajax to post comments to a certain page, I have everything working, except for when the user posts a comment I would like it to show immediately without refreshing. The php code I have to display the comments is:

```
 <?php 

require('connect.php');

$query = "select * \n"

. " from comments inner join blogposts on comments.comment_post_id = blogposts.id WHERE blogposts.id = '$s_post_id' ORDER BY comments.id DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$c_comment_by = $row['comment_by']; 
$c_comment_content = $row['comment_content']; 

?>
<div class="comment_box">
<p><?php echo $c_comment_by;?></p>
<p><?php echo $c_comment_content;?></p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
}
```

and the code I have to post comments is:

```
<?php

$post_comment = $_POST['p_post_comment'];
$post_id = $_POST['p_post_id'];
$post_comment_by = "Undefined";

if ($post_comment){

            if(require('connect.php')){

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES (

                                       '',
                                            '$post_id',
                                      '$post_comment_by',
                                      '$post_comment'

                                    )");

                                    echo "    <script>$('#post_form')[0].reset();</script>";


                                    echo "success!";

                mysql_close();

                }else echo "Could no connect to the database!";


}
else echo "You cannot post empty comments!"

?>
```

JS:

```
function post(){

var post_comment = $('#comment').val();

$.post('comment_parser.php', {p_post_comment:post_comment,p_post_id:<?php echo     $post_id;?>},
function(data)
{
$('#result').html(data);
});

}
```

This is what I have for the refresh so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
setInterval(function() {
$('.comment_box').load('blogpost.php');
}, 3000);. 
});
```

Now what I want to do is to use ajax to refresh the comments every time a new one is added. Without refreshing the whole page, ofcourse. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As it stands, this question more or less says, "do my work for me". Do you have a *specific* question about how to use Ajax in this scenario? If you do not know how to do it at all, you may want to check out a basic tutorial first; you're welcome to ask new questions when you hit a *specific* snag.

Comment: sorry, I edited and inserted my attempt at doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to restructure to an endpoint structure. You'll have a file called "get_comments.php" that returns the newest comments in JSON, then call some JS like this:

```
function load_comments(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "API/get_comments.php",
        data: {post_id: post_id, page: 0, limit: 0}, // If you want to do pagination eventually.
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
             $('#all_comments').html(''); // Clears all HTML

             // Insert each comment
             response.forEach(function(comment){
                 var new_comment = "<div class="comment_box"><p>"+comment.comment_by+"</p><p>"+comment.comment_content+"</p></div>";
                 $('#all_comments').append(new_comment);
             }
        })
    };
}
```

Make sure `post_id` is declared globally somewhere i.e.

```
<head>
  <script>
     var post_id = "<?= $s_post_id ; ?>";
  </script>
</head>
```

Your new PHP file would look like this:

```
require('connect.php');
$query = "select * from comments inner join blogposts on comments.comment_post_id = blogposts.id WHERE blogposts.id = '".$_REQUEST['post_id']."' ORDER BY comments.id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$all_comments = array() ;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $all_comments[] = array("comment_by" => $result[comment_by], "comment_content" => $result[comment_content]);

echo json_encode($all_comments);
```

Of course you'd want to follow good practices everywhere, probably using a template for both server & client side HTML creation, never write MySQL queries like you've written (or that I wrote for you). Use MySQLi, or PDO! Think about what would happen if $s_post_id was somehow equal to `5' OR '1'='1` This would just return every comment.. but what if this was done in a DELETE_COMMENT function, and someone wiped your comment table out completely?

Comment: Thanks so much! I am going to try it out now and then I'll report back!